# Are 'This should be the accepted answer' comments constructive? Should they be flagged?

Tags: discussion, comments, comment-flags, not-constructive

I'm seeing the titled comment more and more these days, perhaps because I'm more aware of it rather than an actually increase of its use but certain from around 2015 onwards it appears to have become a fairly regular thing to do.

In some instances, where a given question doesn't have an accepted answer they can be useful to mark out what has worked, but isn't that the point of upvoting?

In other instances, where the accepted answer is no longer relevant but another answer is, such as through version changes, they can once again be helpful if there are a variety of low vote answers with no clear 'right' one yet standing out.

But in many situations I reckon they are just opinionated noise. Take [this popular question on branch, tag, trunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16142/what-do-branch-tag-and-trunk-mean-in-subversion-repositories). The accepted answer is perfectly acceptable, it covers the question accurately and concisely and it appears many others agree as it is pretty highly voted.

The second answer is also good as it also covers these details but also adds a use case which some people may find nice, however in doing so it over triples the length of the answer.

So both answers are acceptable yet someone has taken it upon themselves to decide that the second answer is the one they prefer and has opted to voice it in the comments.

Isn't it the asker's right/privilege to decide what the accepted answer is and shouldn't we respect that unless there is clear reason not to?

These comments, used in this way, annoy me as it is basically an insult to the author of the question for their poor answer picking skills and an insult to the author of the accepted answer for not fitting the commenter's criteria.

Are these unconstructive, should I flag them as such, or should I just ignore it and move on?

Comment: I flag as not constructive, unless the answer is accepted (and I flag with obsolete). Not constructive is fine either way, actually.

Comment: 'Taken it upon themselves to decide that the second answer is the one they prefer' is mere noise. 'Taken it upon themselves to decide' is just tendentious nonsense. Who else would decide that? And since when shouldn't they 'take it upon themselves' to decide their own preference? And what they have decided is not only that the second answer is the one they prefer, but also that OP is wrong to accept the other answer. I don't see any problem with that, unless they're wrong :-|

Comment: Hey @EJP you're right that bit does read a bit odd. It started off saying 'taken it upon themslves to decided that the second answer is the right one and has...' but I decided to replace the word right since what is right for 1 person isn't always right for another.

Comment: oh so this is why these comments disappear... I was thinking I've gone mad or could see the future. No - turns out simply that the old one got deleted and a new guy thought the same.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment):

> #### When should I comment?
>
> You should submit a comment if you want to:
>
> - Request **clarification** from the author;
> - Leave **constructive criticism** that guides the author in improving the post;
> - Add relevant but **minor or transient information** to a post (e.g. a link to a related question, or an alert to the author that the question has been updated).
>
> #### When shouldn't I comment?
>
> ...
>
> - **Compliments** which do not add new information ("+1, great answer!");

So, especially if the comment does not specify *why* this particular answer is better, it does not add any useful information at all, and flagging it as non-constructive is the right choice. If the commenter did specify a reason, it could be useful information for another visitor having the same question, so I personally would leave it around.

Answer (score 23):

Unless such a comment explains *why* that answer should be accepted (and by explanation I don't mean "because it was helpful to me" or "because I like it"), it should be flagged as "not constructive", because it doesn't contain any useful information. It's not any different from "+1" comments.

Comment: Oh @rene, if only that joke were as funny as it was predictable. :P

Comment: @RyanfaeScotland isn't it nice to have things in life you can rely on? I'm one of those things ...

Comment: Actually, when I'm trying to solve an issue by searching on SO, I often do find it useful to see such a comment even without a reason stated. It prompts me to compare the two answers more carefully, make sure I understand the differences between them, and consider the possibility that the non-accepted one may indeed be better - while without the comment I would just try the accepted answer and use that if it seems to work (unless it is obvious that there is a problem with it of course).

Answer (score 3):

The current answers state: a reason why must be added.

Normally I would agree, but what could you explain in this specific case, really? The reason for accepting an answer is quite simplistic; it was the most useful answer to you. Since that does not imply that an answer must be the most correct and even does not imply that an answer must be without fault, I don't see what you could possibly argue.

And for those cases where no accepted answer exists yet - this is not the way to poke the question author to go accept one. Accepting an answer is by no means mandatory either.

It's more productive to do the reverse scenario - comment why an existing accepted answer is flawed. Now that adds easy to prove information worth considering, even by the folks who tend to look no further than accepted answers.

So yes - in my opinion its always non-constructive.

Answer (score -9):

Yes they can be. It is vexatious to have an obviously incorrect answer as the accepted answer, and it perpetuates the spread of misinformation.

The answer marked itself may have an avalanche of upvotes and this should be enough for the eminence to be obvious.

In addition for old questions, answers may become obsolete, and may no longer be the most useful or the most "acceptable" answer, especially if it was a work-around pending future functionality that has now been delivered.

But if it is just a matter of divided opinion, then no.

Comment: What answer OP accepts isn't for anyone else to decide. If there's a better answer now compared to when the question was asked and the answer was accepted, those answers should be posted and upvoted. "this should be accepted" adds no value what so ever

Comment: @Zoe.. you mean "should have been".  "Should be" has no real meaning if there is already an accepted answer.